# Would it be a problem if my server polls the API every minute or so about 1 of my questions on my list?

Tags: support, api, rate-limit

I know that officially identical requests cannot be done in more than one minute.

But would it be a problem if I had a server which had a list of question IDs (say 10 per user, so reasonable max 10,000 in total) and the server polls the API every minute each question with a pagesize of 0 just to get the number of answers and see if any are new?

Eg: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/2366/answers?pagesize=0

(so basically 100s or 1000s of different requests every minute or 2?)

Comment: Keep in mind that there's a rate limit too: something like no more than 1 request per 1/30 of a second.

Comment: Thanks George (I think thats about 1800 per minute max), Something like web hooks would make this a whole lot easier, and I'm guessing less intensive.